# how to calculate number of days in a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

given the panda data frame below:

```
          Date  % Change  Week days
0    2004-01-02       NaN     Friday
1    2004-01-05      1.09     Monday
2    2004-01-06      0.10    Tuesday
3    2004-01-07      0.34  Wednesday
4    2004-01-08      0.40   Thursday
...         ...       ...        ...
4854 2023-04-17      0.36     Monday
4855 2023-04-18      0.07    Tuesday
4856 2023-04-19     -0.02  Wednesday
```

the data series span over years, and I need to calculate the cumulative days for each month and saving it in a new list.   e.g 01=864 days, 02= 765 days and so on

i know how to take the start date and end date of this dataframe, which can be variable based on the input data, but I found many difficulties on how to count the number of days for each month.

Comment: Please provide a self sufficient, minimal example (no ...)

Comment: Can you please provide what an example outlook looks like? Did you want an extra column in the DataFrame table for the cumulative sum or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `Date` column as `DatetimeIndex` then use `groupby_size` on `dt.month` property:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
out = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month).size().rename('Count').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Date  Count
0     1      5
1     4      3
```

Comment: Thank you work, and now If i want to count the month in de data series? in other words.. how many January,february and so on

Comment: What do you mean. It's what this code does, no? 1 -> January, 4 -> April.

Comment: this code count the total days in each moths through the years the years. Now I'm wondering if I can count the number of months through the years. e.g.. if I have a data series from 2020-01-01 to 2022-03-31, the expected result should be: 3, january 3 february,3 march, 2 aprile and so on

Comment: Try: `df['Date'].dt.to_period('M').drop_duplicates().dt.month.value_counts().rename('Count').reset_index()`